# Can not change header's height in react-native ,navigator

Tags: react-native, navigation, header

Hello I can not change the header height in react native screens header, please help me correct it . I tried using different tools , writing height in headerStyle or using AI ,but nothing helped

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from '../screens/Home';
import ReviewDetails from '../screens/ReviewDetails';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

// Common options for both screens
const commonScreenOptions = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
  },
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  headerTintColor: '#444',
};

function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={commonScreenOptions}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ReviewDetails"
        component={ReviewDetails}
        options={commonScreenOptions}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default HomeStack;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom [header](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator#header) to have full control of styling including `height`. Something like this:

```js
options={{
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    height: 32,
  },
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  headerTintColor: '#444',
  header: ({ route, options }) => {
    const title = getHeaderTitle(options, route.name);
    return (
      <View style={options.headerStyle}>
        <Text style={options.headerTitleStyle}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  },
}}
```